# High Scores on Wii Fit Plus

Tags: nintendo-wii, wii-fit-plus

Does Wii Fit Plus only display your own high scores?  I am sure that yesterday both our scores were there, but now I can only see my own.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible you did a different duration, or a "Plus" or "Super" version of the event instead?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it displays the top 10 scores, and your “Personal Best” score if that score is below the 10th high score.

Answer (score 1):

It should display everyone's high scores in the same top ten list. High score lists on Wii Fit Plus *are* specific to the duration (or amount) of an activity.
If a profile gets removed, so do the high scores associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

It displays both scores, but when one of the players doesn't have Wii fit account and Wii fit Cash meter, then High scores dissapear.